# next.materialize initialization without jQuery

Tags: angular, materialize

Today I visited the 1.0 alpha version of materializecss, Im working with Angular and Im using some of the components that need jQuery initialization like [Side Nav](http://next.materializecss.com/sidenav.html)

The Doc says that is possible to initializate them with:

```
  var elem = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
  var instance = new M.Sidenav(elem, options);
```

Instead of the jQuery way that Im using at the moment:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
  });
```

How can I make It possible? What is M? Maybe I need an example of this new way...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to add the CSS and JS imports either at the top of the `index.html` file or at the `angular-cli.json` file

After that you need to declare a global variable

```
declare var M: any;
```

And then you can use it...

In more detail:

**angular-cli.json**

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/PATH/TO/MATERIALIZE.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/PATH/TO/MATERIALIZE.js"
],
```

**Inside a Component**

```
// Imports
import { ... } from '...';

// Here you declare the M
declare var M: any;

// Then you have the component
@Component({...})
export class ExampleComponent implements onInit { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was missing the declaration of 'M' and this is the only answer I can find that points this out.